# Modeling Matlab Script with Adobe After Effects

Tags: matlab, import, modeling, after-effects

So I am looking for some general advice. For my final project in my Computational Physics class. I have to complete the following problem.

**(4.16 from Computation Physics 2nd Edition By Giordano and Nakanishi)**
*-Carry out a true three-body simulation in which the motions of Earth, Jupiter, and the Sun are all calculated. Since all three bodies are now in motion, it is useful to take the center of mass of the three-body system as the origin, rather than the position of Sun. We also suggest that you give Sun and initial velocity which makes the total momentum of the system exactly zero(so that the center of mass will remain fixed). Study the motion of Earth with different initial conditions. Also, try increasing the mass of Jupiter to 10, 100, and 1000 times its true mass.*

My question: Is it possible to write the code for the problem above, and then import that code(or the result) into Adobe After Effects to model the three-body simulation? My teacher has expressed that if i am able to do so, he would be inclined to give me extra credit, which i desperately need.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is not a concrete question about programming and thus is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [for this site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Yes, it is almost certainly possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do some scripting in After Effects, but the language is Javascript (or rather, ExtendScript), not Matlab. I would do everything in a javascript: first calculate your solution (3 streams of position data), and use these to keyframe the corresponding layers in After Effects. You will have to learn a bit of the After Effects object model, but in that case you wont need much: the Layer object and how to keyframe its position property. You should go to the Adobe After Effects scripting forum https://forums.adobe.com/community/aftereffects_general_discussion/ae_scripting/ for some script examples.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer! So, that leads me to the following questions. 1) Is there enough similarity between Matlab and Javascript, that i can write my initial program in Matlab, then convert the code to Java as needed?(My program has to be written in MATLAB for my computational course) 2) How much knowledge of java will i need to accurately model the three-body problem above?

Comment: I can't tell about Matlab, i'm not using it. And it is Javascript, not Java, which is quite a different thing. I think that the there is very little to know about javascript for that project, and same to port to AfterEffects, provided you have experience with that software.